# Is there an efficient way of solving $y^{(4)}+2y''+y=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplace-transform

> Is there an efficient way of solving $y^{(4)}+2y''+y=0$?

I wanted to use the following theorem:

[image]

However, the characteristic equation is unfactorable when its highest factor is 3! So I was thinking about using Laplace transform, by first finding $\hat\Phi(s)=(sI-A)^{-1}$, where $A$ is the companion matrix, and transforming it back into the t-domain. But this is a $4\times 4$ matrix I have to find the inverse to and the row operations get super messy with the $s$ variable involved.

So I am wondering...is there a better way that is around this scope of difficulty? Or do I just fight it out with the algebra and find $\hat\Phi(s)$?

Comment: I think your best bet is to use the Laplace transform. Wolfram gives me
$$
y(x) = c_1\cos x + c_2x\cos x +c_3\sin x + c_4x\sin x.
$$

Comment: I don't see what your comments about the "highest factor is 3!" are all about. In any case solving the characteristic equation gives your fundamental system of solutions as $e^{it}$, $e^{-it}$, $te^{it}$, $te^{-it}$.

Comment: substitute $s=r^2 \implies s^2+2s+1=0$ it's easy to factorize

Comment: @Isham Hello, is the characteristic equation $\lambda^{4}+2\lambda+1=0$ or am I wrong? If I let $s=\lambda^{2}$, how do I get the term $2s$?

Comment: @numericalorange You are wrong: the characteristic equation is $\lambda^4+2\lambda^2+1=0$.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y^{(4)}+2y''+y=0$$
The characteristic equation is:
$$R^4+2R^2+1=0$$
Substitute $s=R^2$
$$s^2+2s+1=0 \implies (s+1)^2=0$$
Then
$$(R^2+1)^2=0 \implies (R^2-i^2)^2=0 \implies (R-i)^2(R+i)^2=0$$
$$\implies R=i, R=-i$$
Mutiplicity 2

And solve the equation. Laplace transform will take you more time here.
$$y(x)=c_1\cos x+c_2x\cos x+c_3 \sin x+c_4x \sin x$$

Answer (score 1):

By letting $y=e^{mx}$, in the ODE we get $m=i,i,-i,-i$ (two repeated roots).
So $$y=(C_1+c_2x)e^{ix}+(D_1+D_2x)e^{-ix} \implies (E_1+E_2x)\cos x+ (F_1+F_2x)\sin x.$$